# How to submit a string array in a form Rails 4.2

Tags: arrays, ruby, postgresql, rails-postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have a model `message` with a string array attribute `recipients`. Here's what my `messages_controller.rb` looks like:

```
def new
  @message = Message.new
  @message.attachments = params[:attachments]
end
def create
  @message = Message.new(create_params)
  @message.user_id = current_user.id
  @message.attachments = params[:message][:attachments]
  @message.recipients = params[:message][:recipients]
  save_message or render 'new'
end
private
  def create_params
    params.require(:message).permit(:object, :content,
                                  :recipients,
                                  :attachments)
  end
```

And the _fields.html.erb looks like this:

```
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
<%= f.label :object %>
<%= f.text_field :object, class: "form-control" %>
<%= f.label :recipients %>
<%= f.text_field :recipients, multiple: true, class: "form-control" %>
<%= f.label :attachments %><br>
<%= f.file_field :attachments, multiple: true, class: 'form-control' %><br />
<%= f.label :content %>
<%= f.text_area :content, class: "form-control" %>
```

The problem is that it saves the `recipients` array like this:

```
["recipient_1, recipient_2"]
```

instead of

```
["recipient_1", "recipient_2"]
```

I want to be able to retrieve recipient[0] = recipient_1 and not recipient[0] = whole array.

It's probably something simple, but I can't find the fix.
All inputs appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is returning a single string because the input is a text field. If you want to utilize a text field for this then just expect that the input will be comma-separated and split the input:

```
@message.recipients = params[:message][:recipients].split(',')

# or, if it's wrapped in an array
# @message.recipients = params[:message][:recipients][0].split(',')
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually for `permit` you pass it a collection of :symbols. These keys must represent scalar values only. But arrays are represented differently by an empty array.

Try this:

```
def create_params
    params.require(:message).permit(:object,
                                    :content,
                                    :attachments,
                                    recipients: [])
end
```

And the field in your form:

```
<%= f.text_field_tag "recipients[]", :recipients, multiple: true, class: "form-control" %>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I had to wrap it around a block `{recipients: []}` and it still gave me `[["recipient_1, recipient_2"]]`

Comment: This tricky, but you actually have to put array declarations at the **end** of your permit parameters ! So in the above piece of code the `:attachments` is messing things up, because it is after the `recipients` declaration. Or maybe they fixed that in newest Rails version ?

Comment: @CyrilDD Thanks for the catch, I didn't know that.